# How do I create a translation / move storyboard dynamically through code?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create the following storyboard in code:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="m_activateIdentityStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty=
                  "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="-22"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I have tried the following:

```
    Storyboard board = new Storyboard();
    Storyboard.SetTarget(board, view);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(board,
      new PropertyPath(CompositeTransform.TranslateYProperty));

    DoubleAnimation upAnim = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
      Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)),
      From = 0,
      To = -22,
      RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(1)
    };
    board.Children.Add(upAnim);
```

But it does nothing. I'm pretty sure I specifying the wrong PropertyPath, but I don't know what I'm supposed to put in it, or even how I am supposed to research what to put in it. I also dont understand what "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" means and how to translate that into c#.

Thanks!
swine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct c# code for your animation should be something like this,

```
    // initialize a new instance of the CompositeTransform which allows you 
    // apply multiple different transforms to your image
    this.image.RenderTransform = new CompositeTransform();

    // create the timeline
    var animation = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
    // add key frames to the timeline
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame { KeyTime = TimeSpan.Zero, Value = 0 });
    animation.KeyFrames.Add(new EasingDoubleKeyFrame { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200), Value = -22 });
    // notice the first parameter takes a timeline object not the storyboard itself
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"));
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, image);

    // create the storyboard
    var storyboard = new Storyboard() { RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
    // add the timeline to your storyboard
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);

    // start the annimation
    storyboard.Begin();
```

I have put in some comments and hopefully they make sense to you. :)

Comment: Now how do I prevent the Image from being clipping to the boundary of the Panel it is moving inside?